# installing WCF on mod_mono with mono 2.10.2

Tags: wcf, apache, mono, opensuse

i want hosting a WCF service on a opensuse 11.2 with apache 2.2.13 and mono 2.10.2, but i don't have found anything that explain me how in detail, and all my tentative are wrong. Someone may help me?
Thanks in advance
F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have partially resolved my problem using visual studio for creating the service and generating in  another project the proxy. Then publishing on linux machine the service with this web.config configuration:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WcfService2.Service1Behavior"
        name="WcfService2.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0"
          contract="WcfService2.IService1" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WcfService2.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"  />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

and adding this two lines to mod_mono.conf

```
MonoServerPath "/usr/bin/mod-mono-server4"
ddType application/x-asp-net .svc
```

The problem i mean is only that on mono the mechanism of wsdl doesn't work. But calling normally the service works.
This is the error if i call from my prowser the service:

```
<Fault><Code><Value>a:InternalServiceFault</Value></Code><Reason><Text xml:lang="">The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  The server may be able to return exception details (it depends on the server settings).</Text></Reason></Fault>
```